# Grails - one-to-many table relationship across packages

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have two classes, each in a different packages and there is a one-to-many relationship between them. How is this done? I have:

```
package one
class History {
  String name
  static hasMany = [fielderror:FieldError]
}

package two
class FieldError {
  String fieldName
  static belongsTo = [history:History]
}
```

If they were in the same package, this would work, but they are not. The error in **package one** is:

> Groovy:Apparent variable 'FieldError' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class.

So I guess I need to make **package one** aware of **package two** and vice versa. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an import like for any class in another package:

```
import one.FieldError
```

Comment: Import two.FieldError - Thats what I thought, but I get an error "Groovy:unable to resolve class two.FieldError". I replace FieldError with "*" and then it goes back to original error!

Comment: Okay, you are right. Seems the IDE I was using - springsource once it detects some errors, it keeps them around (or gets lost) even when you fix them. Rebooted my IDE and of course the errors went away and that import statements works.